# Setting up AWS credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am having problems configuring my AWS credentials on Serverless using my terminal. Once I place:

```sh
serverless config credentials --provider aws --key xx --secret xxx --profile serverless-admin2
```

After that the system responds "setting up aws..." and doesn't do anything else. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The command just only creates a **new entry** in your `~/.aws/credentials` file. Thus to check if it worked, inspect `~/.aws/credentials` and see if `[serverless-admin2]` profile was created with your aws keys.

If not, you can add the profile yourself there.